# How do I stop myself from creating light? I'm trying to change the lighting but I create my own light and I shine all over everything

Tags: light, lighting

[image: I always shine on everything]I want to edit my scene's lighting, but wherever I go, I create light. how do I stop this?

Comment: either you are god or you are in Solid mode (top right of your 3D view)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Anyway, press Z and instead of Solid, select Rendered, it should look better.

Comment: Love how this question is phrased and love moonboots' response (i was thinking the same thing) Really made my day : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 'Solid' view mode, Blender automatically lights surfaces based on their angle to the viewport. In order to see the effect of your lighting you need to switch to 'Rendered' mode which you can do by simply clicking the relevant Viewport Shading icon :

[image: rendered view]